# How can I get a value from a React-Bootstrap form on submit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to get the value of a form input using React-Bootstrap. What is the standard procedure to get the form value from a react bootstrap form on a functional component in react?

```
export default function SpouseForm() {
  const dispatch = useContext(DispatchContext);

  return (
    <Form>
      <Row>
        <Col xs={12} md={12} lg={{ span: 6, offset: 3 }}>
          <InputGroup className="mb-3">
            <InputGroup.Prepend>
              <InputGroup.Text>Age</InputGroup.Text>
            </InputGroup.Prepend>
            <FormControl /> <--------- I want to get this value on submit /////////////////
      </InputGroup>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Col xs={12} md={12} lg={{ span: 6, offset: 3 }}>
          <Button
            onClick={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault()
              dispatch({ type: "SPOUSE_AGE", spouseAge: e.target.value }); < ----- tried to get it here, not working
              router.push('/children')
            }}
            style={{ width: '100%' }}
            type="submit"
            variant="outline-primary"
            size="lg" >Next</Button>{' '}
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Form>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's either you have [controlled input](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) and keep track of its value in real-time stored within your state:

```js
const { useState } = React,
      { render } = ReactDOM,
      { Form , Button } = ReactBootstrap,
      rootNode = document.getElementById('root')

const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(),
        onInput = ({target:{value}}) => setValue(value),
        onFormSubmit = e => {
          e.preventDefault()
          console.log(value)
          setValue()
        }
  
  return (
    <Form onSubmit={onFormSubmit}>
      <Form.Control 
        type="text" 
        onChange={onInput} 
        value={value}
      />
      <Button type="submit">
        Submit
      </Button>
    </Form>
  )
}

render (
  <App />,
  rootNode
)
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" /><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/react-bootstrap@next/dist/react-bootstrap.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

Or, the other way around, you have [uncontrolled inputs](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) and access [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) upon submit:

```js
const { useState } = React,
      { render } = ReactDOM,
      { Form , Button } = ReactBootstrap,
      rootNode = document.getElementById('root')

const App = () => {
  const onFormSubmit = e => {
          e.preventDefault()
          const formData = new FormData(e.target),
                formDataObj = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries())
          console.log(formDataObj)
        }
  
  return (
    <Form onSubmit={onFormSubmit}>
      <Form.Control type="text" name="myInput" />
      <Button type="submit">
        Submit
      </Button>
    </Form>
  )
}

render (
  <App />,
  rootNode
)
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" /><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/react-bootstrap@next/dist/react-bootstrap.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Note: According to the react documentation: "In most cases, we recommend using controlled components to implement forms.".  https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html

Comment: @java-addict301 : While I agree (and use controlled inputs most of the times) there still are good use cases for uncontrolled ones, which you may prefer for performance reasons (like, if you need to avoid state changes and subsequent re-renders as user types in), as an example.

Comment: Good point @YevgenGorbunkov.  As a React nooby, I don't understand why the preferred case is form controlled components for the very reason you pointed out (performance reasons) - I just quotes reactjs.org.  Do you usually use uncontrolled for your forms?

Comment: @YevhenHorbunkov Where is the `FormData` class/object coming from?

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka it is a [standard web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

Comment: Thank YOU!!!! Had no idea FormData was a thing!!!! Also fyi you should give all your form tags a name. This way it will provide you a nice json to work with!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

One of your problems is that FormData will only create entries for input fields that have BOTH: 1. A name and 2. A value.

It appears from your code that the you are missing the name. You should also capture the event like Yevhen shows: onSubmit

Doing both these things fixed the problem for me.

```
    <Form onSubmit={onFormSubmit}>
              <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="test1" >
                  <Form.Label>Some TextX</Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="type something" name={"value1"} />
              </Form.Group>
             
              <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                  Submit
              </Button>
</Form>

const onFormSubmit = (e:any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData(e.target);
        formData.append('title','John');
        let i=0;
        // @ts-ignore
        for (let [key, value] of formData.entries()) {
            console.log(i++,key, value);
        }
    };
```